# Encrypt without password, decrypt only with password

Tags: aes, pbkdf-2, password-based-encryption

I'm trying to implement a password manager and I want to achieve this behaviour.

1. User enters a master password **once** (eg. when the program is first run) and a key/hash of some sort is derived and stored (from which the original password **cannot** be recovered)
2. User can then choose to store data in the password bank eg. 
   `store --id=myid --data=datatoencrypt`. This data is encrypted using AES **without** having to prompt for a password using the stored key from step 1

At this point the encrypted data stored **cannot** be recovered without the original password, but new data can be added **without** the original password

```
store get --id=myid
Please enter your password: *******
The data is: datatoencrypt
```

I hope this makes sense. Any pointers on how I can achieve this? (I'm guessing a combination of asymmetric and symmetric encryption

Comment: ... I really hope this is not meant to compete with password managers like KeePass in terms of security?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't this be just the usual asymmetric encryption, as if you were encrypting e.g. email with GnuPG?

Create a private key, store it password protected (this is your master password). Anything you need to save, encrypt using the corresponding public key (no need for a password). But only the private key can decrypt your data items, and you need to enter the password to use that.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I've been overthinking this. My plan was to use AES for the actual encryption since it's significantly faster and use an asymmetric encryption for deriving the AES key but now that I think about it it's not possible because AES is symmetric

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs  Combining symmetric with asymmetric encryption is quite standard, as it is done in all the standards for email or file encryption. It's called [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)